# How to omit creating pivot

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

My task is to create a table with daily price change, but the problem is every day I have slightly different set of rows (e.g. the product is sold).

- I need to base on already existing pivot table cause it contains all of the names of products I need.
- The pivot don't have "visible" values I am interested in ( they are in pivot cache but are not used, I only need to add "sum of PRICE")
- cant change existing pivot values cause it ruins another part of the report

What i am already using is that I make a copy of an existing pivot and paste it on new sheet then change values of it. If daily change is more than +/- 5% it needs to be pasted into final table.

Is there a way to omit creating second pivot, can I somehow use the data that is not visible?

Comment: if the data source has both days, you might be able to use % Difference From https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/show-percent-difference-previous-years-excel-pivot-tables/

Comment: yes, that helped with the calculations, but it still requires to create second pivot